# Camera info not being published by v4l2_camera_node

Tags: camera-calibration, ros-humble

I am trying to use a web cam with the `aruco_ros` package to estimate the pose of an ArUco marker. The package I am using to get the camera images is the `v4l2_camera` package but I am having a problem, `v4l2_camera_node` is publishing `/camera_info` without the information like this:

```
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1694104949
    nanosec: 776459841
  frame_id: ''
height: 480
width: 640
distortion_model: ''
d: []
k:
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
r:
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
p:
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
binning_x: 0
binning_y: 0
roi:
  x_offset: 0
  y_offset: 0
  height: 0
  width: 0
  do_rectify: false
```

I already calibrated my camera with the `camera_calibration` package and saved the results. When I run `v4l2_camera_node` I get a couple errors:

```
[INFO] [1694106573.030815912] [v4l2_camera]: Driver: uvcvideo
[INFO] [1694106573.031204681] [v4l2_camera]: Version: 393743
[INFO] [1694106573.031261676] [v4l2_camera]: Device: Integrated Camera: Integrated C
[INFO] [1694106573.031301723] [v4l2_camera]: Location: usb-0000:00:14.0-8
[INFO] [1694106573.031338402] [v4l2_camera]: Capabilities:
[INFO] [1694106573.031374606] [v4l2_camera]:   Read/write: NO
[INFO] [1694106573.031411856] [v4l2_camera]:   Streaming: YES
[INFO] [1694106573.031454594] [v4l2_camera]: Current pixel format: YUYV @ 640x480
[INFO] [1694106573.031619333] [v4l2_camera]: Available pixel formats: 
[INFO] [1694106573.031663159] [v4l2_camera]:   MJPG - Motion-JPEG
[INFO] [1694106573.031699589] [v4l2_camera]:   YUYV - YUYV 4:2:2
[INFO] [1694106573.031733434] [v4l2_camera]: Available controls: 
[INFO] [1694106573.031775698] [v4l2_camera]:   Brightness (1) = 128
[INFO] [1694106573.031820045] [v4l2_camera]:   Contrast (1) = 32
[INFO] [1694106573.031860894] [v4l2_camera]:   Saturation (1) = 64
[INFO] [1694106573.032499536] [v4l2_camera]:   Hue (1) = 0
[INFO] [1694106573.032556092] [v4l2_camera]:   White Balance, Automatic (2) = 1
[INFO] [1694106573.032598837] [v4l2_camera]:   Gamma (1) = 120
[INFO] [1694106573.032640281] [v4l2_camera]:   Power Line Frequency (3) = 1
[INFO] [1694106573.033182735] [v4l2_camera]:   White Balance Temperature (1) = 4600 [inactive]
[INFO] [1694106573.033259586] [v4l2_camera]:   Sharpness (1) = 0
[INFO] [1694106573.033303499] [v4l2_camera]:   Backlight Compensation (1) = 1
[ERROR] [1694106573.033357630] [v4l2_camera]: Failed getting value for control 10092545: Permission denied (13); returning 0!
[INFO] [1694106573.033395094] [v4l2_camera]:   Camera Controls (6) = 0
[INFO] [1694106573.033426300] [v4l2_camera]:   Auto Exposure (3) = 3
[INFO] [1694106573.033979184] [v4l2_camera]:   Exposure Time, Absolute (1) = 156 [inactive]
[INFO] [1694106573.034107672] [v4l2_camera]:   Exposure, Dynamic Framerate (2) = 0
[WARN] [1694106573.035972783] [v4l2_camera]: Control type not currently supported: 6, for control: Camera Controls
[INFO] [1694106573.037698539] [v4l2_camera]: Starting camera
[WARN] [1694106573.248302454] [v4l2_camera]: Image encoding not the same as requested output, performing possibly slow conversion: yuv422_yuy2 => rgb8
[INFO] [1694106573.254334950] [v4l2_camera]: using default calibration URL
[INFO] [1694106573.254442777] [v4l2_camera]: camera calibration URL: file:///home/automatebase/.ros/camera_info/integrated_camera:_integrated_c.yaml
[ERROR] [1694106573.254593077] [camera_calibration_parsers]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/automatebase/.ros/camera_info/integrated_camera:_integrated_c.yaml]
[WARN] [1694106573.254640735] [v4l2_camera]: Camera calibration file /home/automatebase/.ros/camera_info/integrated_camera:_integrated_c.yaml not found
```

There is no /camera_info folder inside /.ros, shoud I just create that folder and paste the the YAML file from the calibration?

[EDIT] Using `usb_cam` package:

I also tried using the `usb_cam` package instead of the `v4l2_camera` package, however I have the same problem, the `usb_camera_node` gives me the error:

```
[ERROR] [1694444697.653173284] [usb_cam]: Invalid camera calibration URL: /home/automatebase/.ros/camera_info/camera_info.yaml
```

And the camera info is not published. This is the output from the calibration node in case that helps:

````
mono pinhole calibration...
D = [0.14880426526992593, -0.03236985997669252, -0.01781091717583487, 0.0236618003681507, 0.0]
K = [674.5058161190959, 0.0, 346.95961390137086, 0.0, 675.1512129728582, 198.31744172459904, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
R = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
P = [702.38525390625, 0.0, 355.45461080182577, 0.0, 0.0, 709.22509765625, 193.2878561560501, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
None
# oST version 5.0 parameters


[image]

width
640

height
480

[camera]

camera matrix
674.505816 0.000000 346.959614
0.000000 675.151213 198.317442
0.000000 0.000000 1.000000

distortion
0.148804 -0.032370 -0.017811 0.023662 0.000000

rectification
1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 1.000000

projection
702.385254 0.000000 355.454611 0.000000
0.000000 709.225098 193.287856 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000

('Wrote calibration data to', '/tmp/calibrationdata.tar.gz')
D = [0.14880426526992593, -0.03236985997669252, -0.01781091717583487, 0.0236618003681507, 0.0]
K = [674.5058161190959, 0.0, 346.95961390137086, 0.0, 675.1512129728582, 198.31744172459904, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
R = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
P = [702.38525390625, 0.0, 355.45461080182577, 0.0, 0.0, 709.22509765625, 193.2878561560501, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
# oST version 5.0 parameters


[image]

width
640

height
480

[camera]

camera matrix
674.505816 0.000000 346.959614
0.000000 675.151213 198.317442
0.000000 0.000000 1.000000

distortion
0.148804 -0.032370 -0.017811 0.023662 0.000000

rectification
1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 1.000000

projection
702.385254 0.000000 355.454611 0.000000
0.000000 709.225098 193.287856 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Not available

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

Please pay attenton to the following log messages:

```
[ERROR] [1694106573.033357630] [v4l2_camera]: Failed getting value for control 10092545: Permission denied (13); returning 0!
...
[ERROR] [1694106573.254593077] [camera_calibration_parsers]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/automatebase/.ros/camera_info/integrated_camera:_integrated_c.yaml]
[WARN] [1694106573.254640735] [v4l2_camera]: Camera calibration file /home/automatebase/.ros/camera_info/integrated_camera:_integrated_c.yaml not found
```

For some reason, the calibration file can not be created.

1. Please make sure that `/home/automatebase/.ros/camera_info/` path exists. If note please create it as shown below:

   ```
   mkdir -p /home/automatebase/.ros/camera_info/
   ```
2. Your file name is `integrated_camera:_integrated_c.yaml` which is ususal and not recommended. This could be the cause of your problem. Please fix it.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, created the folder and change the file name but didnt work so I tried using another package but it is still not working, I added the results to the original question.